echarts4r e_mark_area() different fill colours
I am trying to highlight different periods of a timeseries plot using the echarts4r package - reprex below.
df <- data.frame(Date = seq(from = as.Date("2023-01-01"), by = "day", length.out = 100),
                 Count = sample(100:150, size = 100, replace = TRUE))

p1_sta <- as.Date("2023-01-01")
p1_end <- as.Date("2023-01-15")

p2_sta <- as.Date("2023-02-01")
p2_end <- as.Date("2023-03-01")

p3_sta <- as.Date("2023-04-01")
p3_end <- as.Date("2024-04-10")

df %>%
  group_by(Date) %>% 
  summarise(Count = sum(Count)) %>% 
  e_charts(Date, barCategoryGap = "1%") %>%
  e_line(Count, color = "grey", name = "", symbolSize = 3) %>%
  e_mark_area(
    data = list(
      list(xAxis = p1_sta, name = "A"), 
      list(xAxis = p1_end)
    ), itemStyle = list(color = "lightgreen", opacity = 0.1)) %>% 
  e_mark_area(
    data = list(
      list(xAxis = p2_sta, name = "B"), 
      list(xAxis = p2_end)
    ), itemStyle = list(color = "orange", opacity = 0.1)) %>% 
  e_mark_area(
    data = list(
      list(xAxis = p3_sta, name = "C"), 
      list(xAxis = p3_end)
    ), itemStyle = list(color = "red", opacity = 0.1)) %>% 
  e_x_axis(show = FALSE) %>% 
  e_y_axis(name = "Beds Occupied", nameLocation ="middle",
           nameTextStyle = list(padding = c(0,0,20,0))) %>%
  e_tooltip(axisPointer = list(type = "cross"),
            trigger = "axis",
            backgroundColor = "rgba(40, 40, 40, 0.75)",
            borderColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)", textStyle = list(color = "#fcfcff")) %>%
  e_legend(bottom = "1%") %>%
  e_grid(right = "1%", left = "4%", bottom = "2%", top = "10%")


This code highlights the areas, but the same "lightgreen" colour is applied to all three. My goal is to have different colours for each highlighted section.
I have been able to find someone with a similar problem here:  https://github.com/JohnCoene/echarts4r/issues/99 -- and someone responding has provided what looks like a working answer, but, unfortunately, I haven't been successful in adjusting the code to apply to my example.
Any help really appreciated.
Thanks.

One option which works for me is to move the specs for the itemStyle into the specs of the data= attribute.
library(echarts4r)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

set.seed(123)

df %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  summarise(Count = sum(Count)) %>%
  e_charts(Date, barCategoryGap = "1%") %>%
  e_line(Count, color = "grey", name = "", symbolSize = 3) %>%
  e_mark_area(
    data = list(
      list(
        xAxis = p1_sta,
        name = "A",
        itemStyle = list(color = "lightgreen", opacity = 0.5)
      ),
      list(xAxis = p1_end)
    )
  ) %>%
  e_mark_area(
    data = list(
      list(
        xAxis = p2_sta, name = "B",
        itemStyle = list(color = "orange", opacity = 0.1)
      ),
      list(xAxis = p2_end)
    )
  ) %>%
  e_mark_area(
    data = list(
      list(
        xAxis = p3_sta, name = "C",
        itemStyle = list(color = "red", opacity = 0.1)
      ),
      list(xAxis = p3_end)
    )
  ) %>%
  e_x_axis(show = FALSE) %>%
  e_y_axis(
    name = "Beds Occupied", nameLocation = "middle",
    nameTextStyle = list(padding = c(0, 0, 20, 0))
  ) %>%
  e_tooltip(
    axisPointer = list(type = "cross"),
    trigger = "axis",
    backgroundColor = "rgba(40, 40, 40, 0.75)",
    borderColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)", textStyle = list(color = "#fcfcff")
  ) %>%
  e_legend(bottom = "1%") %>%
  e_grid(right = "1%", left = "4%", bottom = "2%", top = "10%")



this works perfectly, thank you so much
